# Summing columns from different files in a list

Tags: r

so I have a list of 20 files each with 3 columns and about a million rows. I put them in a list and then what I am trying to do is have something like this:

```
    x         y              Sum
---------------------------------
     1         1               28
     .         .                .  
     .         .                .  
     .         .                .  
900000    900000
```

The first two columns, x and y, are the same for each file, I Just need the sum of the third column for each file and have a new single file like the one above with the x and y column. I Tried this to sum the columns but R never seems to finish computing it.

```
Sum <- do.call(rowSums,lapply(new,function(df){(df[3])}))
```

I then tried this but it gives me 11 numbers, and what I need is to have 1 million different numbrers

`Sum <- do.call(rbind,lapply(new,function(df){sum(df[3])}))`

Any ideas?

Edit:

I used this:

`#Get the third column alone
third<- lapply(new,function(df){df[3]})`

`#Sum the column
sum <- Reduce("+", Third)`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please clarify what you have and what you need. Particularly the latter is not clear to me. A reproducable example would help even more!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should return all the rows. You can do the following

```
# create sample data
d1 <- data.table(x=rep(1,10), y=rep(2,10), z = rep(1:5, each=2))
d2 <- data.table(x=rep(1,10), y=rep(2,10), z = rep(10:14, each=2))
dll <- list(d1, d2)

## add a group column
for(i in seq_along(dll)){
    dll[[i]] <- cbind(dll[[i]], group=i)
}

# convert list to df
mdf <- do.call('rbind', dll)

# convert df to data.table
setDT(mdf)
mdf[,sum := sum(z), group]
mdf[,group := NULL]
```